# Change the select to custom select with down arrow in react quill

Tags: react-quill

Is there a way I can change this select drop down to a custom select drop down with a down arrow instead of the default quill arrows?

[image: quill select]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select `ql-picker-label`, and makes its default icon (the double pointing arrow) which is enclosed within an `svg` hidden, by setting `display: none`. Then, since the text itself is enclosed within the `::before` pseudo-element, you can set the `background-image` on the `ql-picker-label` itself. The code below should be self-explanatory. However, because the text is within `::before` element, I could not find an easy way to make space between the icon and the text. Perhaps, you can edit the icon image, and manually insert space before it.

*This sample code below will select all `ql-picker-label` elements, you can avoid this behavior by entering more specific selectors.*

```
.ql-picker-label svg {
  display: none;
}

.ql-picker-label{
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg fill='black' height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24' width='24' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><path d='M7 10l5 5 5-5z'/><path d='M0 0h24v24H0z' fill='none'/></svg>");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center right;
}
```

Comment: i tried and it didn't work you can check the code here https://codesandbox.io/s/react-quill-full-toolbar-forked-nrtyuf?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: What if  i want it to be interactive icon, arrow up and arrow down with hoovering effect same as paragraph?